# Why I've to specify two values when identifying the aws resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I do not know why I've to specify two values when identifying an AWS resource in terraform. For example,

```
resource "aws_instance" "test"
```

I understand that "aws_instance" is the resource type but what about the other one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a terraform expert, but my understanding of the second value is the "Logical ID" of the instance much like Cloudformation, i.e. this is what it will be referred to inside terraform.  Meaning that if you create that instance, and then want to export it's IP somewhere else you can then access the resource properties through the second value, like so:

```
"${aws_instance.test.private_ip}"
```

Comment: But when I identify that resource as 
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  name = "websrv"
  ami            = "${var.ami}"
}
Why I have to write a different name?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you give is the "NAME" of the resource you have created. The "NAME" parameter must be set. You can see its importance while using the output of resource that gives input to another resource creation.

Comment: But when I identify that resource as 
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  name = "websrv"
  ami            = "${var.ami}"
}
Why I have to write a different name?

Comment: The name you gave as "websrv" is the name of the resource that created on AWS, but the name "test" is the unique name that you will inside the terraform file.                                                                                      Remember "websrv" is the name of your ec2 instance but "test" is the name given in terraform to identify that specific resource.

Answer (score 0):

While the resource name (`"test"` in your example) is not useful in a simple configuration with only one or two resources, an important feature of Terraform is using the attributes of one resource to populate another.

A common example of this in AWS is creating VPC and subnet objects:

```
variable "app_name" {}
variable "env_name" {}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.app_name}-${var.env_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "a" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 4, 1})"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.app_name}-${var.env_name}-usw2a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "b" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 4, 2})"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2b"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.app_name}-${var.env_name}-usw2b"
  }
}
```

In this example, the name `"main"` of the `"aws_vpc"` resource is used as part of references from the two subnets back to the VPC. This allows Terraform to populate the subnet `vpc_id` even though its value won't be known until the VPC is created. It also avoids duplicating the VPC's base CIDR block in the subnets, instead calculating a new subnet prefix dynamically.

Notice that the resource names are different than the tag `Name` on each object, because they have a different scope: the Terraform resource names are required to be unique only within a single module, and so they will usually have short names that just distinguish any resources of the same type within that one module. The Name tags -- and, for some other resource types, the unique resource name -- must instead be unique either within an entire AWS region or possibly across a whole AWS partition (in the case of S3, for example).

The different purpose of these Terraform-specific names becomes particularly important for more complicated systems where the same module is instantiated multiple times in different configurations, such as creating similar infrastructure across different environments. In this case the Terraform-specific names will be the same across all uses of the module -- since the module source code is identical -- but they will need to have distinct names within AWS itself, e.g. qualified by the environment name they belong to. The usual way to achieve that is to add variables to your modules to specify a subsystem and an environment and then use that to produce a consistent naming scheme for the objects in AWS, while Terraform itself just uses its local names for references in configuration.